# Importing AMD modules that don’t use exports with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

#### The setting

I am trying to load existing AMD modules with TypeScript.

To demonstrate my problem, here is an `app.ts` file that loads an AMD module named `my_amd_module.js`:

```js
// app.ts

import * as amd_func from './my_amd_module';

function main(): void {
  console.log(amd_func());
}

main();
```

The following TypeScript configuration is used:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

And I am using Webpack to bundle the `app.ts` file in a package named `app-bundle.js` that can be run by a browser:

```
// webpack.config.js

'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: './app.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'app-bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  }
};
```

#### The working version

When the `my_amd_module.js` looks as following, everything is working fine. Notice that I am referencing `'module'` as a dependency and bind the function `foo` to it’s `exports` property which is one possible flavor of using AMD.

```
// my_amd_module.js

define(['module'], function(module) {
  function foo () {
    return 'Hello from AMD!';
  }

  module.exports = foo;
});
```

#### The not working version

But when I am using the alternative syntax of defining an AMD module with a return value instead of assigning to `exports`

```
// my_amd_module.js

define(function() {
  function foo () {
    return 'Hello from AMD!';
  }

  return foo;
});
```

then the TypeScript compiler complains with the following message:

```sh
ERROR in ./app.ts
(1,27): error TS2306: File '/[...]/src/my_amd_module.js' is not a module.
```

But the `app-bundle.js` file is still generated and everything works in the browser.

The alternative syntax I am using in this case is, for example, [described by RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#altsyntax) or [in the AMD specification itself](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md#factory-).

#### My question

Are AMD modules that define their exported value with a `return` value instead of assigning to `exports` not supported by TypeScript? Is this the reason why the compiler is complaining? And why is everything compiled, despite this complaint?

Answer (score 0):

> Are AMD modules that define their exported value with a return value instead of assigning to exports not supported by TypeScript

Yes. Apparently it is not detected as an external module and inferred to be `global` and hence not allowed to be `require`d. Please raise an issue here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues